# How to prove that there exists two distinct points $c$ and $d$ such that $f'(c)f'(d)=1$ where $f$ is continuous on [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ be a continuous function which is differentiable  on $(a,b)$ and $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$. Prove that there exists two distinct points $c$ and $d$ such that $f'(c)f'(d)=1$.

Since the function is continuous on closed interval and differentiable on open interval therefore by mean value theorem there exists $c$ such that      $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$.

From there I got $f'(c)=-1$ but I am unable to find $c$ and $d$ such that $f'(c)=-1$ and $f'(d)=-1$ so that I could say $f'(c)f'(d)=1$.

And by fixed point theorem I got $f'(x)$ is greater than $1$ since $f$ does not have unique fixed point, but how to continue further?

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove there are $\xi$, $\eta$ with $f'(\xi)f'(\eta)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580702/prove-there-are-xi-eta-with-f-xif-eta-1) – found quickly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f%27(c)f%27(d)%3D1%24&p=1)

Comment: Or this more general result: [How to prove there exist distinct $a_{i}$ such $f'(a_{1})f'(a_{2})f'(a_{3})\cdots f'(a_{n})=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1373408).